# using syntax to apply variable labels used in another file

Tags: syntax, spss

Is there a way to generate the syntax used to label the variable and value of an spss file?

I have an SPSS file which contains about 200 variables. I created a copy of the file in CSV format. I made several changes of the data so I would like to create a new spss file. I would like to copy the variable and value labels of that file to my new file.

Comment: Good question! Easiest way I know of without making the syntax for all of the value and variable labels is to use the `APPLY DICTIONARY` command to transfer all of the metadata from the old to the new dataset.

Comment: Thank you Andy! I never thought that functionality exist. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same question. I'm adding a working snippet based on the comment by Andy W.

```
Apply Dictionary from *
/Source Variables = varWithLabelAndValues 
/Target Variables = varNeedingLabelAndValues
/Varinfo VARLABEL VALLABELs=replace .
```